# stylesheet_link_tag for LESS.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stylesheet, less

What would the Rails equivalent of the stylesheet_link_tag be for this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/stylesheets/style.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style.less', :rel => 'stylesheet/less' %>
```